# Updating database entrys from JSP page

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

i'm getting some strange problem with my JSP/Servlet/EclipseLink-JPA project. I'm running on Apache Tomcat 7.0.27.0 directly from NetBeans (EE pack) 7.2.1, database is PostgresSQL
Here's some code: 
jsp page responsible for displaying table with products, index.jsp:

> ```
> <%
>             for(Product product:ProductController.getProducts()){
>                 %><tr>
>                     <td><%
>                     out.print(product.getName());
>                                            %></td>
>                     <td><%
>                     out.print(product.getPrice());
>                                             %></td>
>                     <td><%
>                     out.print(product.getUnit());
>                                            %></td>
>                     <td><%
>                     out.print(product.getSales().size());
>                                            %></td>
>                     <td><a target=\"_blank\" href="viewSales.jsp?id=<%=product.getId_product()%>">sales</a> </td>
>                     <td>
>                         <a target="_blank" href="updateProduct.jsp?id=<%=product.getId_product()%>&name=<%=product.getName()%>&price=<%=product.getPrice()%>&unit=<%=product.getUnit()%>">edit</a>
>                     </td>
>                 </tr><%
>             }
>         %>
> ```

two links in last cells are for viewing sales and updating products accordingly. We are interested in last one, leading to another jsp:

```
<form action="UpdateProduct" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="id" style="display:none" value="<%=request.getParameter("id") %>">            
            <input type="text" name="name" size="30" placeholder="Название" value="<%=request.getParameter("name")%>"><br>
            <input type="text" name="price" size="30" placeholder="Цена" value="<%=request.getParameter("price")%>"><br>
            <input type="text" name="unit" size="30" placeholder="Единица" value="<%=request.getParameter("unit")%>"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить">
        </form>
```

from here we are going to servlet UpdateProduct.java:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        Long id = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("price"));
        String units = request.getParameter("unit");            
        ProductController.updateProduct(id, name, price, units);

        response.sendRedirect("");
    } finally {            
        out.close();
    }
}
```

ProductcController.updateProduct works fine (i can see it in database directly).

But when i return to first page (index.jsp), i do not see any changes, no matter how many times i refresh it. My closest guess is that Apache Tomcat (i'm running on it) somehow save data from 1st request somewhere in context and do not refresh it on demand. Also, strange thing is that adding product works just fine.

Comment: You did not show the interesting part: `ProductController.getProducts()`

Comment: It's not very interesting actually





`public static List<Product> getProducts(){
        EntityManager em = MyEntityManager.getEM();        
        return em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p ORDER BY p.id_product").getResultList();
    }`

Comment: home, ty for pointing out that something is wrong with getProducts() - it is actually returning old data. So i guess this question is not about jsp/servlets but about something in wrong controller/postgres.

Comment: You might not flush your entity manager. First, try to `em.flush()` after inserting a new product and `em.refresh()` before the query.

Comment: home, thank you again, i've added

`List products = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p ORDER BY p.id_product").getResultList();
        for(Object product:products){
            em.refresh(product);
        }`
into getProducts() and it worked. Yet, can you explain me why it didn't w/o it? I have to refresh items one by one now, and it works like selecting every single item on it's own - kinda costly.

Comment: Worst code I have ever seen. Never write Java code in JSPs.

Comment: Michael-O, thanks for you feedback. It was my first experience in jsp/servlets, so i'm not surprised it looks awful to you :)
 By "Never write Java code in JSPs" you mean i should never write another jsp or it is a common advice? If it is, how should i use jsp? ._. What's the point, if not writing java code in it?

Comment: @StoumTheCat I fear there are more issues in your application. You should not have one global entity manager. Read about transaction management and entity manager injection in multi-thread code - keep in mind that one servlet instance will be called concurrently in reality...

Comment: "in multi-thread code" - that explains alot, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by refreshing each product before displaying it

```
List products = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Product p ORDER BY p.id_product").getResultList(); 
    for(Object product:products){ 
    em.refresh(product);
     }
```

I guess it can be improved by saving updated product's id and refreshing only them.

Origin of the problem is unknow, because in other project that implement same thing but with swing GUI everything worked fine w/o refresh. Maybe it's something with executing classes at Tomcat.